# unable to edit columns in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have requirement to get a drop down from a column which should have three values. I marked the column as editable with editable: true keyword, even then I am not able to edit. I just need a drop down with two values when i double click on the cell.

```
{headerName: "O", width: 70, valueGetter: this.geValue, editable: true,  cellEditor: 'select',
    cellEditorParams: {
        values: ['Yes', 'No']}
    }
```

I am using select here but not rick select because i am not using ag-grid enterprise. I am also setting these below properties for all the rows.

```
  suppressCellSelection: true,
  suppressMovableColumns: true,
  suppressRowClickSelection: false,
```

I need help to find if I am missing anything here. I am not getting a drop down when I double click on cell.

I could finally figure out why I could not edit the cell even if I declare it editable. Because css is adding a class as shown below

```
<div class="ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell ag-group-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-value" colid="O" style="width: 54px; left: 48px;"></div>
```

I have to remove ag-cell-not-inline editing class from the div. I am not sure how. Is there any option to remove default class from grid options?

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrmoser/p4aewr4w/4/) using the same parameters that you have. The athlete column is the one with the dropdown. It seems to be editable there, except for when `suppressCellSelection` is set to true it doesn't return the cell to normal until it has detected a change in the value.

Comment: '<div class="ag-cell-not-inline-editing" colid="O" style="width: 54px; left: 48px;"></div>'---> ag-cell-not-inline-editing class is being added to the div and that class is not allowing me to edit cell. I think it is the css property that is being set on my css file '.ag-cell-not-inline-editing{padding:2px}.ag-fresh' is there anyway to remove that class dyamically from grid option as set class as 'ag-cell-inline-editing'

Comment: when a cell gets edited, there are DOM elements that are added into the cell's div. Changing a class won't create those DOM elements. does the JSFiddle that I created work in your browser?